# Missing memberfunction of QOpenGLExtraFunctions

Tags: qt, opengl, virtualbox, mesa

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 in a VirtualBox. As soon as I want to build my project I get this error message

```
error: ‘class QOpenGLExtraFunctions’ has no member named ‘glTexBuffer’; did you mean ‘glReadBuffer’?
             MBGL.glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_RGBA32F, m_buildingColorBuffer);
```

So I assumed that the OpenGL Version isn't correct. I updated everything and
"glxInfo" gives me this information

```
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.1.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.1.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 18.1.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

Which seems fine because glTexBuffer is supported with 3.x

Is there anything else what I could do or is there an alternative for glTexBuffer()

Comment: This is funny: In online doc. for Qt 5.11 it is mentioned: [`QOpenGLExtraFunctions::glTexBuffer()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qopenglextrafunctions.html#glTexBuffer). On our side, we work with Qt 5.9.2. So, I looked into online doc. for Qt 5.9 as well: [No `QOpenGLExtraFunctions::glTexBuffer()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qopenglextrafunctions.html#glTexBuffer). It seems it has been added with Qt 5.10.

Comment: Based on your comment I updated my Qt from 5.9.6 to 5.11 but it doesn't help

Comment: Actually, the doc. is just a hint (though it is usually embedded in / generated from source code). Did you check whether the `glTexBuffer()` really appears somewhere in the Qt header files? If found you might see that it is dependent from certain macros/settings...

Comment: Nope it is not there, I checked that already^^

Comment: Based on your hint i looked through the different header files and found that the functions I need are in #include <QOpenGLFunctions_4_4_Core>
It works now

Comment: I had a look onto woboq.org and found it there: [`QOpenGLExtraFunctions::glTexBuffer()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/opengl/qopenglextrafunctions.h.html#_ZN21QOpenGLExtraFunctions11glTexBufferEjjj). I'm not sure what version source code this is - assuming HEAD. (It's remarked with OpenGL ES 3.2.)